# ImageIO - could not find ColorSync function

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I am getting a warning in the console when running iOS 8:

```
*** ImageIO - could not find ColorSync function
```

while using AFNetworking:

```
[_contentImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:msg.filePath] placeholderImage:nil];
```

This warning has never shown in iOS 7.1

Who can help me please?

Comment: This is happening with `SDWebImage` as well.